# put image inside another image android

Tags: android, android-layout

how can put an image inside another image?

ex :
[image]

[image]

I try using a relative layout background image and the inside layout put image put not work.

Comment: Create a mask (hexagon) and apply using [Porter-Duff](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode)

Answer (score 0):

I think using a `FrameLayout` with background will work, try the following code would work:

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/outer_image">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/inner_image"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: how can shape image inside as 6 corners like this frame